# Catching all exceptions in current thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, exception

In my web application I have a one way async WCF service. In this service I want to catch all exceptions like I do in global.asax Application_Error.
I've tried to handle these events:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (s,e) => { //some logic };
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += (s,e) => { //some logic };
```

even tried:

```
//this one is for Win Forms Application
Application.ThreadException += (s,e) => { //some logic };
```

and

```
//this one is for Web Application
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Error += (s,e) => { //some logic };
```

But none of these handlers are reached.

Any ideas, what else can I try?

Comment: You need to post the code of the thread itself, otherwise, there isn't enough information to guide you.

Answer (score 2):

If you put those lines of code into a web page they will be lost. Why?

Because Web Page has a limited lifetime. To keep your event handling survive you need to put it into the global asax file.

Comment: It's not a Web page and there is no ASAX file.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Global.asax works just fine for WCF in ASP.NET

Comment: @Gev you said "_In my **web application** I have a one way async WCF service. In this service I want to catch all exceptions like I do in **global.asax** Application_Error._"
That's why my answer.

Comment: @jgauffin : no It doesn't if you have one way service.

Comment: @gev: Show me the source that says that global.asax doesn't work for them.

Comment: @jgauffin: I don't want to catch exceptions on global.asax. I want to catch them on the service itself.

Comment: @Gev: you can add a global.asax to WCF projects too.

Comment: @jgauffin: Thanks a lot, I think this will work as I want! :)

Answer (score 2):

WCF allows you to insert an object that implements IErrorHandler into the Errorhandlers of the Dispatcher.

The [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) has sample code.

Comment: The Service is One Way, should the Dispatcher be able to handle this errors?

Comment: I know what OneWay is and I don't see why the 'normal' error interception wouldn't work.